# ¿Cómo simplificar la inicialización de un diccionario? C#

Tags: c#, inicializacion

Me está saliendo una advertencia que me dice:

**IDE0028 La inicialización de la recopilación se pueden simplificar**

Este es el código:

```
public class Controler
{
    delegate bool Delegate();
    Dictionary<string, Delegate> map;

    public Controler()
    {
        map = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    }
}
```

Me está pidiendo que simplifique esto:

```
map = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
```

¿Se puede simplificar eso? Y si no...
¿Se puede hacer algo para que no salga esta advertencia?

> Estoy usando Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Versión 16.8.3

Gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de evitar la advertencia seria usar #pragma, lo puedes colocar de forma generica que desactive todos los mensajes de una clase o un error o advertencia en particular.

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0028  // de esta forma es error en particular, 
si le quitas el codigo del error te desactiva todas las advertencias.

public class Controler
{
    delegate bool Delegate();
    Dictionary<string, Delegate> map;

    public Controler()
    {
        map = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Estupendo!! Muchas gracias Ramiro!!